# Use the same rule to N patterns with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can the following syntax be written on one line?

```
RewriteRule ^dir1/images/(.*) images/$1
RewriteRule ^dir2/images/(.*) images/$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be written on one line using regex OR clause. See code below:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:dir1|dir2)/images/(.*)$ images/$1 [L]
```